# UNION in SQL queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm currently playing with the query

```
SELECT sex, count(sex) as [count], problem1, problem2, problem3
from myTable
group by sex, problem1, problem2, problem3
order by sex, problem1, problem2, problem3
```

and this will give me a count of all possible bit cominbations for each sex (1, 1,1 or 1,01) etc

Is there any way I can use a union query to get the TOTAL number of males and females in an extra column?

so

[image]

sex   count   problem1   problem2   problem3   (count of sex goes here)

If I can't do that for both sexes, is there a way I could do it for just one?

edited: the last column, total# of women is what I want to add.

Comment: Have you checked out the ROLLUP operator? [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Also - i dont understand your data.... ( bit combinations ?)

Comment: strange. you apply agregate function (count) to field SEX and also supply it in GROUP BY clause... can you show table structure and explain business logic?

Comment: I thought about using that query, and then UNION select sex from mytable where sex='f' and displaying that on every row.  don't know if it's possible

Comment: I did not know about this, I'll read up on it.

Comment: @heximal in this particular example this is all from one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using a temporary table. One note though: Your counts will be repeated for each row of a particular sex.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    sex varchar(10), -- or whatever datatype you are using
    totalCount INT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
(
    sex,
    totalCount
)
SELECT
    sex,
    count(1)
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    sex

SELECT m.sex, count(m.sex) as [count], m.problem1, m.problem2, m.problem3, t.totalCount
from myTable AS m
JOIN #Temp AS t
ON t.sex = m.sex
group by m.sex, m.problem1, m.problem2, m.problem3, t.totalCount
order by m.sex, m.problem1, m.problem2, m.problem3, t.totalCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the `UNION` supposed to go, but if you wish to extend the resultset with an additional column that include a `COUNT` of all items, you can use the following:

```
SELECT sex, count(sex) as [count], problem1, problem2, problem3, (select count(1) from myTable) as TotalCount
from myTable
...
```

BTW, not sure you'd like to do that because the value is going to be the same for all rows. Usually, we'll write a separate query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sex, count(sex) as [count], problem1, problem2, problem3, s.s_total
from myTable
, (select count( sex ) s_total from mytable) s
group by sex, problem1, problem2, problem3, s.s_total
order by sex, problem1, problem2, problem3
```

you can do whatever you like in the subquery part

(edit - needs to group by the same s_total)

Comment: what does s.s_total stand for?

Comment: s is the alias for that inline view...  s_total is the column alias for the total count inside there.